# Can i use a SAS drive on my backplane?

Tags: sata, sas

I have a Lian Li PC-011 Dynamic XL case.  It comes with 4 hot pluggable HDD slots that are accessible from the back.  I know they work for SATA drives, as i have 1 4TB drive plugged into it right now that im using.  It is connected to a SATA port on my motherboard.

I also have a CHenbro ITX SOHO case with a 4 bay hot swap backplane that i KNOW supports both SATA and SAS ***drives***.  The backplane has SATA connectors at the HBA/MB side.  I also have a SAS HBA with SATA breakout cables which are plugged into the backplane.  I run 4 HGST SAS drives off of this.  The problem is that the HBA is meant for a server and the little ITX case just doesnt have the airflow and im afraid my HBA is going to get too hot and meet an early death.

So, can i move my SAS drives into my Lian Li case and connect my HBA to the backplane as i did before?  This case is cavernous and has 9 fans and great airflow.  I cant seem to find any documentation on whether the backplane in my lian li will accept SAS.  Or am i being dumb?  Is the backplane just the bridge and it will work as long as i have a SAS HBA on the other end?  Or is there something different electrically that would only allow SATA drives to work in my backplane and not SAS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

super late (but was looking for a sas backplane, to swap out my sata backplane, but for a different box than yours, and this popped up)...

...easiest way to tell is to look at the connector for the backplane (remove a drive tray): if the connector has a divider between the power and data sides (like a motherboard memory chip slot has a little notch somewhere middle-ish), then it's only sata

**all sata work in sas backplanes, but sas do NOT work in sata only backplanes** (they just won't push in without use of a hammer and ending up physically broken)

if only your sas backplane would fit into the box with nice airflow (that probably has a sata only backplane): tray and screw-hole placement isn't exactly standard, but you could luck out!